# How to characterize a wideband RF ferrite transformer

Tags: rf, transformer, ferrite

[Transformer models](http://k5tra.net/tech%20library/RF%20transformers/Wideband%20Transformers.pdf) incorporating intrinsic and parasitic elements are well known:

[image]

The mutual and leakage inductances are calculated from measurements of the primary and secondary winding inductances at a frequency where the parasitic capacitive reactances are high.

$$M=k\sqrt{L_P L_S} \text{ for } k=\frac{v2}{v1}\sqrt{\frac{L_S}{L_P}}$$
$$\text{in which }{v_2} \text{ and } {v_1} \text{ are measured at a "mid-band" frequency.} $$
$$L_{l1}=L_P-nM \text{ and } L_{l2}=L_S-\frac{M}{n}$$

What happens for transformers wound on ferrite cores whose permeability drops dramatically with increasing frequency? The primary and secondary magnetizing inductances may drop enough that their reactances no longer "disappear" in favor of the parasitic capacitances. Does the "direct" measurement of primary and secondary leakage inductance by short circuiting the secondary and primary, respectively, give better results?

Comment: Many RF wideband transformers are wound with transmission lines. Mutual coupling at the high-frequency end of the transformer operating range depends far less on the core's *magnetic* coupling, and much more on *transmission-line* coupling. The underlying core mostly extends the low-frequency end, where its permeability dominates over the transmission-line (which has become very short length, electrically). So ask, "is my model valid for a transmission line?"

Comment: @glen_geek Sadly, simulation indicates that a transmission-line transformer will not operate properly in my application.